# ..._1.default is not a constructor when testing TypeScript with Mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to get unit tests with mocha to work. I'm using typescript which gets compiled down to plain javascript with tsc. I'm always getting the error:

```
    src\index.ts:22
        [new FrontendEndpoint(), ...],
         ^
    TypeError: v1_1.default is not a constructor
```

I approached two ways (and ran into the same problem twice):

First I created a dummy test `test.test.ts`, importing some of my modules for testing purposes:

```
    import { APIServer } from './../api/index';
    import { describe } from 'mocha';
    import FrontendEndpoint from '../api/endpoints/frontend/v1';
    import { SocketConnector } from '../api/sockets/socketio';

    describe('TestTest', () => {
        it('should run', (done) => {
            const server = new APIServer(4000, [new FrontendEndpoint()], new SocketConnector([]));
            done();
        });
    });
```

1. Using ts-mocha

   - Installed ts-mocha, mocha, @types/mocha
   - Ran `ts-mocha src/test/test.test.ts`
2. Using mocha & compiled ts files

   - Installed mocha, @types/mocha
   - Ran `mocha build/test/test.test.js`

Both ways produce the error above.

`index.ts` looks like this:

```
    import FrontendEndpoint from './api/endpoints/frontend/v1';
    [...]
    new FrontendEndpoint()
```

Compiled (index.js):

```
    [...]
    const v1_1 = require("./api/endpoints/frontend/v1");
    [...]
    new v1_1.default()
```

And `frontend/v1.ts`:

```
    export default class FrontendEndpoint {
        [...]
    }
```

Compiled (v1.js):

```
    class FrontendEndpoint {
        [...]
    }
    exports.default = FrontendEndpoint;
```

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "src/types"
        ],
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "outDir": "build"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "coverage",
        "build",
        "logs"
    ],
}
```

It seems to only have issues with default exports. **Why don't they work as expected?** When running the app using `node build/index.js` everything is working fine, the default exports/imports work as expected.

I'm having the same issues when trying to add unit tests to my frontend React app with Webpack, with Mocha and with Jest. Do I miss something completely?

Comment: Someone else mentioned problems with default imports and Jest just the other day... Hmmm.

Comment: *"And the `frontend/v1.ts`: ... `exports.default = FrontendEndpoint;`"* Apologies if the answer is obvious, I'm not a big TypeScript guy, but why not `export default FrontendEndpoint;`? You're using ESM syntax for the import, but CommonJS syntax for the export...?

Comment: I may have made this a bit unclear. This is javascript compiled from typescript. It's how the typescript compiler handles default exports.

Comment: You said *"And the `frontend/v1.ts:` followed by code. So naturally I assumed that was code in `frontend/v1.ts`. With the edit, I have no idea what that code is. Would you please show both the TypeScript for the export and the JavaScript, clearly labelled (as you did with `index.ts`).

Comment: Sure, sorry. I added the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

While debugging my tests I discovered that some of the exports are not being called. This is due to **cyclic dependencies** of the files, that prevented them from being exported correctly.

After finding these cycles using https://github.com/pahen/madge and resolving them, running tests is working just fine.